# Python scipy chisquare returns different values than R chisquare

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, chi-squared

I am trying to use `scipy.stats.chisquare`. I have built a toy example:

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as sps

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: sps.chisquare(np.array([38,27,23,17,11,4]), np.array([98, 100, 80, 85,60,23]))
Out[11]: (240.74951271813072, 5.302429887719704e-50)
```

The same example in `R` returns:

```
> chisq.test(matrix(c(38,27,23,17,11,4,98,100,80,85,60,23), ncol=2))

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  matrix(c(38, 27, 23, 17, 11, 4, 98, 100, 80, 85, 60, 23), ncol = 2)
X-squared = 7.0762, df = 5, p-value = 0.215
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this `chisq.test` call python equivalent is [`chi2_contingency`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html):

> This function computes the chi-square statistic and p-value for the hypothesis test of independence of the observed frequencies [**in the contingency table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) observed.

```
>>> arr = np.array([38,27,23,17,11,4,98,100,80,85,60,23]).reshape(2,-1)
>>> arr
array([[ 38,  27,  23,  17,  11,   4],
       [ 98, 100,  80,  85,  60,  23]])
>>> chi2, p, dof, expected = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(arr)
>>> chi2, p, dof
(7.0762165124844367, 0.21503342516989818, 5)
```