# Pearson's Chi Square Test Python

Tags: python, scipy, chi-squared

I have two arrays that I would like to do a Pearson's Chi Square test (goodness of fit). I want to test whether or not there is a significant difference between the expected and observed results.

```
observed = [11294, 11830, 10820, 12875]
expected = [10749, 10940, 10271, 11937]
```

I want to compare 11294 with 10749, 11830 with 10940, 10820 with 10271, etc.

Here's what I have

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chisquare
>>> chisquare(f_obs=[11294, 11830, 10820, 12875],f_exp=[10749, 10940, 10271, 11937])
(203.08897607453906, 9.0718379533890424e-44)
```

where 203 is the chi square test statistic and 9.07e-44 is the p value. I'm confused by the results. p-value = 9.07e-44 < 0.05 therefore we reject the null hypothesis and conclude that there is a significant difference between the observed and expected results. This isn't correct because the numbers are so close. How do I fix this?

Comment: I get a low value from p-value tables and an identical answer from mathematica as well. There's nothing wrong with the answer you're getting.

Comment: I think this is the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492419/python-scipy-chisquare-returns-different-values-than-r-chisquare) (just asked differently): use `chi2_contingency` instead.

Comment: @Evert: That is *not* the same question.  In a contingency table, all the given frequencies are *observed* frequencies, and the expected frequencies are inferred from the observed frequencies.  In the question here, both the observed and expected frequencies are given, so it is not a contingency table problem.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the null hypothesis(H0) says that the two variable(X and Y) are independent, i.e. changing values in X wouldn't affect values in Y.

For example, X = [1,2,3,4] and Y = [2,4,6,8]

If you calculate the "p-value" using any method out there for this case, it should come out to be a very small value, implying that there is a very low chance of this case following the null hypothesis, i.e. a very low chance that X and Y are independent of each other.

It means it will never follow the Null Hypothesis here and these two variables are dependent on each other, in a form of Y = 2X.

In your case also, p-value score of **9.0718379533890424e-44** means the same thing, i.e. small value indicates that there is a very low chance it would suffice the null hypothesis and it means that **observed** and **expected** are related to each other and there is no *independence* between them.

Ps. You are correct about this.