# How to get scipy.stats.chisquare to function properly

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have 2 input files of identical size/shape, however the data they contain has a different resolution and I am looking to perform a chi squared test on them.

The input files are 500 lines long and contain 4 columns delineated by spaces, I am trying to test the second column of each input file against the other.

My code is as follows:

```
# Import statements

C = pl.loadtxt("input_1.txt")
D = pl.loadtxt("input_2.txt")

col2_C = C[:,1]
col2_D = D[:,1]

f_obs = np.array([col2_C])
f_exp = np.array([col2_D])

chisquare(f_obs, f_exp)
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
ValueError: df <= 0
```

I don't even understand what it is complaining about here.

I have tried several other syntaxes within the script, each of which also resulted in various errors:

This one was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866961/pearsons-chi-square-test-python).

```
chisquare = f_obs=[col2_C], f_exp=[col2_D])

TypeError: chisquare() takes at least one positional argument
```

Then I tried

```
chisquare = f_obs(col2_C), F_exp=[col2_D)

NameError: name 'f_obs' is not defined
```

I also tried several other syntactical tweaks but nothing to any avail. If anybody could please help me get this running I would appreciate it greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure you are importing [`chisquare`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) from `scipy.stats`.  Numpy has the function [`numpy.random.chisquare`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.chisquare.html), but that does not do a statistical test.  It generates samples from a chi-square probability distribution.

So be sure you use:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
```

There is a second problem.
As slices of the two-dimensional array returned by `loadtxt`, `col2_C` and `col2_D` are one-dimensional numpy arrays, so there is no need to use, for example, `np.array([col2_C])` when you pass these to `chisquare`.  Just use `col2_C` and `col2_D` directly:

```
chisquare(col2_C, col2_D)
```

Wrapping the arrays with `np.array` like you did is causing the problem.  `chisquare` accepts multidimensional arrays and an `axis` argument.  When you do `f_exp = np.array([col2_C])` (with the extra square brackets), `f_exp` is actually a two-dimensional array, with shape (1, 500).  Similarly `f_obs` has shape (1, 500).  The default `axis` argument of `chisquare` is 0.  So when you called `chisquare(f_obs, f_exp)`, you were asking `chisquare` to perform 500 chi-square tests, with each test having a single observed and expected value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I got the same error: `ValueError: df <= 0`. 

For more info, the line before it says `File "mtrand.pyx", line 2084,  in mtrand.RandomStata.chisquare (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:12332)`. If this helps at all?

Comment: Oh!  You're using `numpy.random.chisquare`!  That is not a chi-squared test.  It just generates samples from the chi-squared distribution.  For the chi-squared test, use `scipy.stats.chisquare`.

Comment: @Vlad: I updated my answer with information about the `chisquare` functions in `numpy.random` and `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Thanks again! For whatever reason it insisted on calling the numpy version, even though I removed numpy entirely from the script. I solved it by using `from scipy.stats import chisquare as chi` which did the trick.